# Want to test the server with logged data

Tags: http, jmeter, request, k6

I am logging raw http requests to kafka.

```
GET /api/v1/user

GET /api/v1/friends

POST /api/v2/problem/solve HTTP/1.1
Host: domain.com
Content-Length:111
Cookie:...

{
"input":"{...}"
}
```

Obstruction, such as sessions and JWT tokens, will modify the source of the server.

I would like to make new requests based on these data, test them, and see the results, can you recommend a suitable solution?

I looked for Jmeter, K6, and others, but it was not a satisfactory solution.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a load testing tool which will take the stuff you put to Kafka and generate end-to-end load test out of it? Good luck.

JMeter might be used in at least 2 ways:

1. If you're capable of exporting messages from Kafka into files you could consider using [HTTP Raw Request sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-http-raw-request-sampler-when-and-how-to-use-it) which has more or less the same syntax as your records
2. If not, you could use [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) for reading the records from Kafka and constructing the HTTP Request out of them, the JMeter API class you will need is [HTTPSamplerProxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerProxy.html)

Comment: I used it as a Jmeter. I was able to use it even though there was room for improvement.
Is there any other tool that consists of CLI?